# how to automatic increase specific column value in mysql

Tags: mysql

```
Table 1
id | uname | flag
1  |  abc  |  0
2  |  abc  |  0
3  |  abc  |  0
4  |  bcd  |  0
5  |  bcd  |  0
6  |  cdf  |  0
7  |  ghi  |  0
8  |  ghi  |  0
```

I want to increase flag value according to their uname occurrence, starting from 0

```
Table 1
id | uname | flag
1  |  abc  |  2
2  |  abc  |  1
3  |  abc  |  0
4  |  bcd  |  1
5  |  bcd  |  0
6  |  cdf  |  0
7  |  ghi  |  1
8  |  ghi  |  0
```

I want to update the table

Comment: Do you want to update the table or select from the table like that?

Comment: And you could share with us what you have tried so far to achieve the desired output!

Comment: Could a user add `9 | ghi` to the table? What would its flag be? What would happen to the other `ghi` flags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify the table using `UPDATE` with variables:

```
set @u := '';
set @rn := 0;

update table1
    set flag = if(@u = uname, @rn := @rn + 1,
                  if(@u := uname, 1, 1)
                 )
    order by uname, id desc;
```

Unfortunately, MySQL does not let you set variables in an update when you use `order by`.  If you want only one statement, then you can use `join`:

```
update table1 t1 join
       (select t1.*,
               (@rn := if(@u = uname, @rn := @rn + 1,
                          if(@u := uname, 1, 1)
                         )
               ) as rn
        from table1 t1 cross join
             (select @rn := 0, @u := '') params
        order by uname, id desc
       ) tt
       on t1.id = tt.id
    set t1.flag = tt.rn;
```